# How to debug a Process Query Operator Event dropped in StreamInsight

Tags: debugging, streaminsight

I have a Process deployed on a self-hosted MSSI server. Bound to this Process I have a simple Pass-through query.

Some events gets dropped here "cep:/Server/Application/Erp/Entity/Event_Events_Process1/Query/StreamableBinding_1/Operator/Stream_1_CleanseInput"

I can see the counter of event dropped going up and I cannot find the reason why it's dropping.

Does anyone know how to debug that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the StreamInsight Event Flow Debugger. Make sure your application exposes the StreamInsight Management Service so you can hook up with the debugger. Then you can record the events which you can debug/step-through in the debugger.

Chances are your events are being dropped because of CTI violations. You might be enqueueing events that based on their start time occurred before the last CTI event.

Answer (score 0):

That's absolutely a CTI violation. You'll see this behavior when you are issuing CTIs declaratively (for example, by specifying AdvanceTimeSettings.IncreasingStartTime or StrictlyIncreasingStartTime). There are a couple of ways that you can handle this: 
1) Enqueue your CTIs programmatically. But you'll have to be careful of violations! (They'll cause an exception). 
2) Tweak your AdvanceTimeSettings to include a Delay. You won't be able to use IncreasingStartTIme or StrictlyIncreasingStart time but you will be able to specify the CTI span duration or event count and a delay. Keep the delay small enough to keep your stream lively but large enough to not drop events. I can't tell you what that is; it'll depend on your events.